# The Natural Join of Mysql

Tags: mysql, natural-join

I'm a little confused about the natural join in mysql.

Suppose that: There are two tables
`table1` has columns: `id, name, address, number (id is the PK of table1)`

`table2` has columns: `id, name, number, money (id is the PK of table2)`

I have already make `"id"` of `table1` a foreign key, referencing the `"id"` of `table2`

and suppose `"number"` in `table1` is `"people's number"` and `"number"` in `table2` is `"telephone number"` those two columns have different meaning but same name

---

When I do the natural join of `table1` and `table2`:

Does mysql just simply check all the columns of `table1` and `table2`, whose name are same, which means that a tuple(row) will be selected ,if and only if, `"id"`, `"name"` and `"number`" must be all same (for example, the `"id"` and `"name"` are same but `"number"` is different, the row will not be selected)?

OR

Does mysql will only check the foreign keys created, which means that a row will be selected , if and only if, `"id"` is same?

---

another question is:

after natural join of `table1` and `table2`, will there be only 1 column called `"id"` or 2 columns called `"table1.id"` and `"table2.id"`??

Thanks indeed!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a natural join for that, you probably need to use a left join.
table1 is the parent table? At least it sounds like it should be, the foreign key reference should be from the parent table inserted into the child table. Where the parent table has one entry per reference id and the child table may have many, one,  or no entries for the referenced id

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.number AS person_number, table2.number AS phone_number
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Queries which only read data will always give the same result regardless of the foreign keys.

From the [JOIN manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html):

> The NATURAL [LEFT] JOIN of two tables is defined to be semantically equivalent to an INNER JOIN or a LEFT JOIN with a USING clause that names all columns that exist in both tables.

If you `SELECT *` the columns which are used in the NATURAL JOIN will appear only once in the result set.

So, in your case:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 NATURAL JOIN table2
```

will become:

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.name, table1.number, table1.address, table2.money
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.id 
           AND table2.name = table1.name 
           AND table2.number = table1.number
```

The order of the columns will proba

Comment: Thanks indeed, so "natural join" is just simply check the columns with same name? I mean that although the "number" columns in two tables have different meanings, they are also used in natural join for the reason that they have same name? The factor to select a row when doing natural join is only depending on "the same name"? Is this true?

Comment: Yes, it looks for names only.